# if statement in ListView flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to have a responsive drawer that when the screen size is higher than X itemExtent is set to default, how could I add a if statement inside a ListView?

```
Widget drawer(context){

  double _containerHeight =  MediaQuery. of(context). size. height;
  int _numberOfListTiles = 16;

  return new Drawer(
    child: Container(
      height: _containerHeight,
      color:  const Color(0xff68778d),
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        itemExtent: _containerHeight/_numberOfListTiles,
        children: [
         
        ],
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

I would like to do:

```
if(_containerHeight < 700){
    itemExtent: _containerHeight/_numberOfListTiles,
}
```

Comment: `itemExtent: _containerHeight < 700 ? _containerHeight/_numberOfListTiles : <somehting>,`

Comment: You can use ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way (in my opinion) would be to instantiate your variable at the top of your drawer method as you did for the _containerHieght and _numberOfListTiles variables.

Your code would then look like that

```
  Widget drawer(context) {
    final double _containerHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final int _numberOfListTiles = 16;
  
    double itemExtent;
  
    if(_containerHeight < 700){
      itemExtent = _containerHeight/_numberOfListTiles;
    } else {
      itemExtent = 100; // Default ?
    }
  
    return new Drawer(
        child: Container(
      height: _containerHeight,
      color: const Color(0xff68778d),
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        itemExtent: _containerHeight / _numberOfListTiles,
        children: [],
      ),
    ));
  }
```